# Complex Dependent Variable

Tags: multiple-regression

I have been running a regression analysis in SPSS where my dependent variable is a composite. By this I mean that it is built up of 7 different items. How can I make it one dependent variable? Because in SPSS you have to give only one dependent variable but I have 7 items for one dependent variable. Is there a way to do this in SPSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can have more dependent variables in a model. Familiarize yourself with the MANOVA/MANCOVA methods.
However, if you want to treat them together (but not some algebric function of them, such as sum or product), then the variables must be put together into a model on a theoretically or logically justified grounds. For example you can have different measures of distress as multiple dependent variables in MANOVA.